# Schroeder's Minkowski Space Integral - Concerns about Wick Rotations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, feynman-diagrams, wick-rotation, dimensional-regularization

In the Appendix of Peskin & Schroeder's "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" there is a list of integrals in Minkowski space. Of particular interest to me is the integral (A.44):
$$
I(\Delta) = \int \frac{d^{d}\ell}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{1}{(\ell^{2} - \Delta)^{n}} = \frac{(-1)^{n} i }{(4\pi)^{d/2}} \frac{\Gamma(n-\tfrac{d}{2})}{\Gamma(n)} \left( \frac{1}{\Delta} \right)^{n-d/2}
$$

$\Delta$ doesn't depend on $\ell$, and Peskin uses the metric $(+---)$. Also, $d$ is the dimension of the space we're looking at, obviously. Peskin derives this integral by Wick rotating to Euclidean space such that $\ell^{0} = i \ell^{0}_{\mathrm{E}}$, and $\ell^{2} = - \ell^{2}_{\mathrm{E}}$ (this is shown in more detail in Chapter 6.3).

(Context: I need to look at the above integral for $n=3$. Supposedly this diverges in $d=4$, which is what I am looking at)

I have two questions about this integral:

- Because of the Wick rotation used, is the above integral exact or does it just work some of the time, or as an approximation? I always thought that it was exact, but recently I had a discussion with someone who said this is not true and a Wick rotation doesn't necessarily yield the exact result. I am confused and would like some clarification on this.
- Secondly, Schroeder uses the $(+---)$ metric (aka the wrong metric for those East Coast fans like myself). This means that $\ell^{2} = (\ell^{0})^2 - ||\boldsymbol{\ell}||^{2}$. I am wondering, does the above integral change in its result if we use the metric $(-+++)$? Mostly I am anticipating that an extra minus sign floats around somewhere since now we'd have $\ell^{2} = -(\ell^{0})^2 + ||\boldsymbol{\ell}^{2}||$.

Comment: Be wary when using equations from P&S as editions have errors detailed on their site. I spent hours questioning a result only to find it was because of an error in P&S. In this case, the integral is perfectly fine.

Comment: Really appreciate the heads up! I never knew that P&S has a website with errata, I'll have to check that out

Answer (score 2):

1. The Euclidean integral
   $$\begin{align} I_E(\Delta) ~:=~&\int \! \frac{d^d\ell_E}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{1}{(\Delta+\ell_E^2)^n}\cr
   ~\stackrel{(A.44)}{=}&\frac{1}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{d}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n)} \Delta^{\frac{d}{2}-n}\end{align}\tag{E}$$
   is [integrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_integrable_function) iff $$n>\frac{d}{2}.$$
   See also the [superficial degree of divergence](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=superficial+degree+divergence).
2. For $n<\frac{d}{2}$ the Euclidean integral $I_E(\Delta)$ is declared in [dimensional regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization) to be equal to the rhs. of eq. (E) via [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).
3. The Minkowski integral in the $(\mp,\pm,\ldots,\pm)$ convention is defined via [Wick rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation)
   $$\ell_M^0~=~i\ell_E^0 \tag{A.43}$$
   to be given by the Euclidean integral
   $$I_M(\Delta) ~:=~\int \! \frac{d^d\ell_M}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{1}{(\Delta\pm\ell_M^2)^n} 
   ~\stackrel{(E)}{:=}~i I_E(\Delta),\tag{M}$$
   respectively.